# How to deconstruct properites on import based on theme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a `colors.ts` file:

```
export const black = '#0C0C0C';
export const blue = '#22618E';
```

and when ever I want to import a specific color I import it like:

```
import {black} from 'Shared';
```

In my Shared folder I have an `index.ts` that exports the colors:

```
export * from './colors';
```

Now I want to be able to export and Import the same way when using a theme.

**Example**

`colors.ts`:

```
const DefaultTheme = {
  black: '#0C0C0C',
  blue: '#22618E',

}

const SpecialTheme= {
  black: 'red',
  blue: 'yellow',

}

export const ColorsBytheme = () => {
 const context = myContext();

 return context.Default? DefaultTheme :SpecialTheme;
}
```

**Problem**:

I can not deconstruct/import the properties directly, this gives me undefined:

```
import {black} from 'Shared';
```

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT:

I have also tried by using a self invoking function when exporting:

```
const ColorsBytheme = () => {
  return DefaultTheme;
};

export default ColorsBytheme();
```

When I import

```
import { black } from 'Shared';
```

It is still undefined

Comment: Your code has a typo in the return statement: `Specialteheme`...could that be the issue?

Comment: I missed updating that part of the code when writing the question.  That would be a issue but it is not in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code example, you are currently exporting `ColorsBytheme` as a function that generates/returns the theme object...therefore, your import/deconstruction would need to look something along the lines of:

```
import { ColorsBytheme } from "Shared"
const { black } = ColorsBytheme();
```

Another option if you wish to have a single line would be to use require instead of import:

```
const { black } = require("Shared").ColorsBytheme()
```

Variables that are imported are just that, static variables.  Functions are not evaluated when they are imported, therefore, in order for the values to be dynamic, the function needs to be executed.

Comment: You are correct but How can I write it so that I get desierd way of importing?

Comment: I have added a one-line version of code that might satisfy your request.